# Nest Js file upload not working with javascript FormData

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have some issues parsing a request made from the front-end using FormData. This is the example request generated from Postman for node.js Axios. If I use the postman app with the request, it works as expected.

Frontend example generated from Postman code feature.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/some_file.jpg')); **//I am using Electron and I have acces to the FileSystem from the client.**
data.append('resizeLargeImage[width]', '1920');
data.append('resizeLargeImage[height]', '1080');
data.append('resizeLargeImage[type]', 'cover');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'localhost:3030/api/v1/optimize-single',
  headers: { 
    'x-api-key': '123', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Backend

```
@Post('/optimize-single')
 @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
 async uploadFile(
   @UploadedFile() file: FileDto,
   @Body() body: UploadFileParametersDto,
   @Res() response: Response,
 ): Promise<any> {
   console.log('file', file, 'body', body);
   **//File is undefined, body is a null Object**

   return await this.appService.uploadFile(file, body, response);
 }
```

Any ideas as to why Nest doesn't recognize this type of request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

If you are in the Renderer process, it works by attaching the file as a blob.

```js
const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
const blob = new Blob([fileBuffer], {
   type: mime.lookup(filePath),
});
formData.append('file', blob, fileName);
```

If you move the same functionality in the Main process it will work as expected with `data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/some_file.jpg'));`